# How do I extract the first element from Pig's STRSPLIT function?

Tags: apache-pig

how do i access the first element from the results of pig's STRSPLIT function? my pig command looks like the following.

```
A = FOREACH mydata GENERATE STRSPLIT(myfield,'.',2) as myfield
```

a value of "myfield" looks like this "john.doe", so STRSPLIT should return ("john","doe"), but i only want the first element ("john" in this case) to be returned as part of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `STRSPLIT` always split the entire string based on the delimiter that you passed and you don't have control to filter the first element alone in the same line. one option could be

```
A = FOREACH mydata GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(myfield,'\\.',2)) as myfield;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myfield;
DUMP B;
```

In `STRSPLIT`, second parameter is regex based delimiter, so you cant directly use '.' as delimiter, you need to escape it with double backslash.

In the relation `B`  we are projecting only `myfield`, so all the other fields will be discarded, finally you will get `john` as output.

Comment: You can select any element from split. Let say here you can select 2nd element by  B = FOREACH A GENERATE myfield.$1;